# Can't suspend system

Tags: ubuntu, debian, power-supply

I just installed Bunsenlabs Linux (which is based on Debian 8) and I have troubles with suspend. When I press suspend button the screen just gets black (not turns off) and after mouse move or key press login screen appears. The strange fact is the network after that is completely down ifconfig does not show eth0 interface. It happens even if the system is just started and no apps have been launched (except default autostart)

I had the same problem with Xubuntu 10.04, bun suspend in Crunchbang worked fine.

I'm not sure, but I suspect the reason is in video driver, I have installed the original one from Nvidia for 8600 GT.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution. I had to install *acpid* package

```
apt-get install acpid
```